# How to generate new random variables after using PCA for dimension reduction?

Tags: pca, simulation, random-generation

I want to be able to generate random variables, that (more or less) match the distribution of some observed data set.
The data set is high dimension and I have reduced the dimension using PCA. Only the first component is significant.
I now want to generate new random variables in the rotated space, then reverse the rotation to get data in the original space.

So if only 1 principal component is significant, I will generate a random variable along that axis. What do I do with the other components? I don't want to be 'fitting the noise'. Also, I want my simulated data to have the same level of noise as the original data. So I can't just simulate along the 1st principal component and then reverse the rotation because then the resulting simulated data will lie along a hyper line.
Is the best strategy just to simulated new variables along each axis but even out the Eigen values for everything except the 1st component, then reverse the rotation?

Comment: Many unclear issues in your question. Starting from `match the distribution of some observed data set` (what properties of the distribution(s)?). Next, you say you wish `have the same level of noise as the original data` and at the same time discard all the "noise" components, leaving only the 1st PC? Why did you do PCA at all?

Comment: @ttnphns - my aim is simulate new variables that have a similar dependence structure as the observed data. The marginal distributions are all standard normal by construction. The key part is the dependence structure. I don't think I said I want to discard the noise. To clarify, I don't want to 'fit' the noise. So if I completely relied on the initial results of the PCA I would simply simulate new variables in the rotated space, reverse the rotation and viola. But that would imply that I believe the structure identified by the eigen vectors is something that will hold in future. To be cont...

Comment: In reality, I only believe that the first component (maybe also the second) represent any signal that I expect to persist. The rest of the vectors are the result of the algorithm fitting the noise. So what I want is to be able to simulate new random variables, with the structure implied by the first (maybe also second) eigenvector, and no other assumptions regarding dependence/correlation, such that the resulting new variables have marginal distributions that are standard normal. I'd also rather not use a copula as I want to achieve dimension reduction.

Comment: I am wondering about the same thing for my thesis. Did you get any answers? I want to use the first component to generate better random variables. How do I do that?